# Prevent systemd-networkd (DHCP) from registering (NTP) time servers

Tags: systemd, dhcp, ntp, systemd-networkd

I'm trying to stop some SBCs (running Debian) from updating their time via the router's own NTP server.  We just want to use a manually configured one such as one from `*.pool.ntp.org`.

I believe the root cause to a particular problem occurs when some routers are reset.  For a short time, the routers appear to be responding with blatantly wrong dates like 01 Jan 2003  (at time of writing it's 2019!), and then return to normal.  This has a really negative impact on the software running on the respective SBCs.  I have no control over these routers and really don't need to use them for NTP.  It's just that the router's DHCP server offers NTP and the Debian SBCs use it automatically.

---

My first thought was to remove `ntp-servers` from `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` eg:

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
```

**But** from what I can read `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` is no longer used by Debian as it uses `systemd-networkd` and `systemd-timesyncd`.

---

Every manual I can find says words to the effect:

> Any per-interface NTP servers obtained from systemd-networkd.service(8) configuration or via DHCP take precedence.

This is specifically the behaviour I need to prevent.  Even if the router can offer ntp-servers we need to prevent these being used as NTP servers.

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120009/117549 help?

Comment: @JeffSchaller as pointed out by another user, this is a different dhcp client.  Though I missed that too.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the documentation [at freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#%5BDHCPv4%5D%20Section%20Options)

You can disable the default behavior using `UseNTP=no` inside the `[DHCPv4]` and `[DHCPv6]`sections of a .network ini-styled file you have to put inside /etc/systemd/network folder.

You also have to activate `DHCP=yes` in the `[Network]` section, in order to make this having an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question, but you can edit the `/etc/ntp.conf` to have the following `server *.pool.ntp.org prefer`. The `prefer` keyword should prefer the specified server over the others in the list.

Comment: AFAIK, `/etc/ntp.conf` isn't read by [systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-timesyncd).  That is, we're not using `ntpd` but systemd's own daemon.